# How to filter Search API index view by taxonomy parent

Tags: views, 8, search

I am using the default database server that comes with search api. I have the Hierarchy Index ticked and I also have the taxonomy field that I want selected.

Could someone give me instructions on how to configure the view to have it filtered by the taxonomy parent/show only the children of the selected parent term? I just want a drop down like you would have with a regular view.

(I got this to work in D7 a while ago but I think that was because the field still retained its taxonomy data type when indexed but now with D8 it has none of that.)

- I can add a field that has a parent relationship but that does nothing.
- I tried adding a field `Vocabulary » Taxonomy term » Term Parents` and tried to filter by that but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out the answer was simpler than I thought.

I was trying to use contextual filters & relationships like other answers said but what worked was just simply adding the `Taxonomy Field` to `Filter Criteria` then selecting the desired `parent`. That's it. No need to add a relationship to it.

**Edit:**
There is still a problem: it doesn't work when using a grouped exposed filter it gives this error:

> A value is required if the label for this item is defined.

Log Message:

> PHP -  Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ...

I tried changing the filter to `Combined field filter` with the Taxonomy as a field so the input would be string but I still get another error.

> PHP - Error: Call to undefined method ...